# Obtener items padre de una receta

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente query donde obtengo la receta de una operación. Esta operaciones esta contada por números `1` puede tener sub-proceso que llamo `1.1` e `1.2` y así esta puede tener sub-proceso también `1.1.1`

con esta query obtengo todo los proceso, pero me gustaría obtener solo los proceso padres los `1` o `2`

```
SELECT * FROM ORDENES where OP='3333' order by Item
```

Mi sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/349b7/2

Tendré que agruparlos de una forma especial?

Espero haberme explicado bien

Comment: Despues de ver tu fiddle me quedaron mas dudas que certezas.. pero no es simplemente verificar que item no contenga un punto????

Comment: Ah y digo dudas, porque no se quien podria querer armar una tabla de esa forma, como que no suena muy logico...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifica tu consulta de esta forma

```
SELECT * 
FROM Operaciones as op 
WHERE op=3333 and item NOT LIKE '%.%'
ORDER BY Item ASC
```

Solo agregue el `not like` para que busque los `items` que tiene puntos y no los traiga.

- [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/349b7/15)

Comment: thanks my budda